# AndEngine: collision of two sprites

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I am developing a small Android game. Before I started using AndEngine, I used the Canvas object and draw everything on it. For testing if two bitmaps collides with each other I checked if their bounding boxes overlap. In case of this, I checked if the overlapping rectangle of both bitmaps got one none transparent pixel in common.
This method worked perfektly and I was able to detect pixel perfect collisions.

Because of some performance issues I started using AndEngine. Collision detection works quiet good but collision tests for two sprites definitly dosent work pixel perfect. The collision tests is "just" a bounding box test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice example of pixel perfect Detection,

[AndEngine - Pixel Perfect Detection](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect)

Comment: these libraries is used old version of And Engine

Answer (score 1):

Below code for collision of two animated sprite works well for me in andEngine without using pixelPerfect class. It may help for you.

```
public boolean isCollides(AnimatedSprite animSprite1 ,AnimatedSprite animSprite2) throws Exception{


float diffX = Math.abs( (animSprite1.getX() +  animSprite1.getWidth()/2 )- 
             (animSprite2.getX() + animSprite2.getWidth()/2 ));
float diffY = Math.abs( (animSprite1.getY() +  animSprite1.getHeight()/2 )- 
             (animSprite2.getY() + animSprite2.getHeight()/2 ));

if(diffX < (animSprite1.getWidth()/2 + animSprite2.getWidth()/3) 
           && diffY < (animSprite1.getHeight()/2 + animSprite2.getHeight()/3)){

   return true;
}else
  return false;
}
```