# if in runnable function not working

Tags: android, andengine, runnable

I will show scoring .   isCollides is a function that checks a collision.

```
if(isCollides(prize, splash))
```

in other function Working well  but in runnable function not working.

```
  private Runnable Scoring =new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

        if(isCollides(prize, splash))
        {
            score++;
            p.setText(":"+score);

        }               

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     mHandler.postDelayed(mStartVamp, 3000);

}
      };


              public boolean isCollides(Sprite Sprite1 ,Sprite Sprite2) throws Exception
                {
            float diffX = Math.abs( (Sprite1.getX() +  Sprite1.getWidth()/2 )- 
                         (Sprite2.getX() + Sprite2.getWidth()/2 ));
            float diffY = Math.abs( (Sprite1.getY() +  Sprite1.getHeight()/2 )- 
                         (Sprite2.getY() + Sprite2.getHeight()/2 ));

            if(diffX < (Sprite1.getWidth()/2 + Sprite2.getWidth()/3) 
                       && diffY < (Sprite1.getHeight()/2 + Sprite2.getHeight()/3))
            {

               return true;
            }
            else{
              return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You sure your `isCollides()` method is working fine??? Did you test the method by calling it with various argument cases??? Are you sure this method is not returning `false` always??

Comment: isCollides() method is working fine.Not always false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386282/andengine-collision-of-two-sprites

Comment: my eyes...are bleeding

Answer (score 0):

Any change you make to AndEngine entities needs to happen on the AndEngine UpdateThread - so your call to `p.setText()` should be enveloped in a `runOnUpdateThread()` call - see this thread for how to - [How can repair this error? "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824236/how-can-repair-this-error-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception/9824583#9824583)